# Safari Loads Nonexistent Mask Icon / Favicon

Tags: safari, favicon

I'm running a new machine and noticed that Safari loads a nonexistent mask favicon on our website. Try any 404 page to see what I mean: https://app.oneoption.com/asdf

Here's a link to the mask icon that used to be on the site: https://app.oneoption.com/Content/images/favicon-mask.svg I've since removed it, cleared Safari Favicon Cache, yet still it appears.

Is there a way to disable mask icons for Safari?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue after deleting the “mask-icon”. Safari seems to aggressively cache icons.

To clear it see this section here, #6 more importantly, to clear your “Template Icons” folder.

https://www.leereamsnyder.com/blog/favicons-in-2021#clearing-the-icon-cache-in-macos-safari-is-deeply-unpleasant